# Object environment texture not showing

Tags: texturing

[image]

For some reason my environment texture isn't showing in my object. No matter what photo I put its always just a shade of white no matter how dark the photo I put in is. It never reflects the photo that's been input.

Comment: Could you please pack your image (FIle > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/ or workupload and share the link

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where your reflections should come from...

1.) If the Photo named "Empty" in your [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/outliner.html) is the object that should be reflected, it never will reflect anything, because it is only an [Empty](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html#image).
These are (afaik) only used as reference images for modeling.

To get a "real" reflective Photo in your Scene, you need a **textured Plane**. There's a great addon inside Blender called "Import Images as Planes". You can just enable it under Edit > Preferences and see if this gives you reflections:
[image]

2.) If the "World" should be reflected, it seems your world shader is basically set up to do this:

[image]

So, just get rid of the mix shader and plug your jpg straight into the background input. The image mapping, however, will be another problem.
[image]